# How to add article id to the end of url in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

At present the url's in my site is in the following format:

http://www.website.com/category/1518-alias

I need to change the format of url's to the following:

http://www.website.com/category/alias-1518

That is, I would like to change the position of the article Id in the url to the end.

Can anyone help me to get this done asap.

Answer (score 0):

If the alias can be numeric this can not be done with a rewrite.

`http://www.website.com/category/1518-2013`

would be rewritten to:

`http://www.website.com/category/2013-1518`

causing ambiguity in the routing.

You'd need to change custom routing to Joomla with either a plugin or by hacking the router code.

http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs#tab=Implementation_Details

P.S.: If you are changing the format of SE friendly URLs in Joomla for SEO purposes, then changing existing URLs to postfix the ID to the end is not going to be a significant gain, if any. If you do this on an existing site you can expect negative ranking fluctuations. If you say why you want to change the format of URLs I could offer alternatives and solutions that address your "why".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux or Cygwin and have GNU sed, try running the following:

```
 sed -i 's/\(http:\/\/[[:alnum:]]*\/[[:alnum:]]*\/\)\([[:digit:]]*\)-\([[:alpha:]]*\)/\1\3-\2/' *.php
```

This tells sed to find all strings of the format "http://[website]/[category]/[number]-[alias]" and swap the [number] and [alias] fields, assuming that your website names use only alphanumeric characters.

If you have multiple files in a nested directory structure, you can do as follows:

```
find /path/to/your/site/data -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/\(http:\/\/[[:alnum:]]*\/[[:alnum:]]*\/\)\([[:digit:]]*\)-\([[:alpha:]]*\)/\1\3-\2/' '{}' ';'
```